# Cmake add_library() doesn't create my library but doesn't return any error

Tags: cmake, dll, build

I'm currently facing a very strange problem. My `CMakeLists.txt` which contains an `add_library()` doesn't create any library at all during the build without any explanation.
I see the `CMakeLists.txt` did execute since the `message()` in it print normally. It works on the computers of the rest of my team. It works on my computer only if I disable multithreading (I don't know why it works when I only have 1 thread).

I added `-v` at the end of the `cmake` command but I only get these additional logs :

```
Dependee "CMakeFiles/lib.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "CMakeFiles/lib.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "CMakeFiles/lib.dir/depend.internal".
```

Anyone could help me to fix that ?

At least, I'm searching for a proper solution do debug Cmake to be able to figure out what's wrong.

It's really strange Cmake doesn't manage to generate my lib without returning any error...

Thx!

PS :

I can't provide the exact code because it belongs to my company but here is what it looks like:

```
add_library(lib SHARED ${SOURCES})
set_target_properties(lib PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${NAME} PREFIX "")

target_link_libraries(lib
  PRIVATE
    library1
    library2
    library3
)
```

Comment: Without the **code** of your project we can hardly help you. See [mcve].

Comment: I've just added the problematic code sample.

Comment: Does this code **reproduce** the problem? If not, then there is a little sense in it. The link from my previous comment explains how to obtain the code which actually reproduces the problem. Failing to build a project with multiple threads usually signals about wrong dependencies. Also make sure that different library targets has different OUTPUT_NAME properties.

Comment: Why would `CMake` generate your library in the first place? Shouldn't it be the compiler that builds your library? `CMake` has only one job and that is to generate the build files (unix makefiles or ninja build files, depending on the tool that you use). When I read your post I have a feeling you run something like `cmake -S. -Bbuild` and expect it to create a library. So which is it? Missing library or missing build files?